# Python imported code taking long to run...why?

Tags: python, performance, time

Here is the code from one python file that I import into another file...

```
class Crop():
    def water(self):
        print('not')

    def harvest(self):
        print('not')

    def __init__(self):
        self.height = 0
class Corn(Crop):
    def water(self):
        self.height = self.height + 2

    def harvest(self):
        if self.height >= 9:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
class Wheat(Crop):
    def water(self):
        self.height = self.height + 1

    def harvest(self):
        if self.height >= 5:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
class Irrigator():
    def __init__(self, load):
        self.load = load

    def irrigate(self, field):
        while self.load > 0:
            self.load = self.load - 1
            field.rain()
```

I take the above code and then I import it into another python file...

```
from farmhelper import *
from random import *

# Field for holding the crops.
class Field():
    def rain(self):
        for i in range(len(self.plants)):
            self.plants[i].water()

    def __init__(self, size, crop):
        self.plants = [0] * size
        for i in range(size):
            self.plants[i] = crop()

class Combine():
    def harvest(self, field):
        quantity = 0
        for i in range(len(field.plants)):
            quantity += field.plants[i].harvest()
        return quantity

# Create fields with 10,000 of each crop

cornField = Field(10000, Corn)
wheatField = Field(10000, Wheat)

# Create irrigators for each field

cornIrrigator = Irrigator(20000)
wheatIrrigator = Irrigator(500)

# Create a combine for harvesting
combine = Combine()


# 90 days ~3 months of growth
for i in range(90):
    # Low chance of rain
    if randint(0, 100) > 95:
        print("It rained")
        cornField.rain()
        wheatField.rain()
    # Always run the irrigators. Since they are never
    # refilled they will quickly run out
    cornIrrigator.irrigate(cornField)
    wheatIrrigator.irrigate(wheatField)

# Gather the crops - DONE
earsOfCorn = combine.harvest(cornField)
headsOfWheat = combine.harvest(wheatField)

# Print the result - DONE
print("Grew", earsOfCorn, "ears of corn")
print("and", headsOfWheat, "heads of wheat")
```

But for some reason it takes around 2 to 3 minutes for the code to run. I believe there is a problem with the latter code posted. If anyone has a solution, lemme know!

Comment: It is taking so long to run because the size provided to the for loops is huge. Try lowering the size provided to the `Field` class to a lower value and see how that affects runtime

Comment: Well, creating tens of thousands of objects isn't instantaneous.

Comment: There is no good reason to set `self.plants` to a list of zeros, then overwrite them with objects. (Preallocating the list slots doesn't speed things up that much.) Just use a list comprehension: `self.plants = [crop() for i in range(size)]`. It's not going to be much faster, though, because the time it takes to call `crop` 10,000 times dwarfs the time it would take to assemble them into a list.

Comment: Also irrigate calls rain 20000 times each call calls water 10000 times so 200,000,000 or 200 million function calls. You don't need to model each plant in a field if they all act the same. And because the irrigate function uses up its entire load of water, your Corn grows to 40000 feet before it can be harvested.

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient design would be to not model every single plant as a separate instance. As it stands you perform the exact same operation on each plant of a field. Just give the Field a size attribute and a crop attribute thus modelling just that one plant per field and multiply any size related outputs by size.

Something along the lines of this:

```
class Field():
    def rain(self):
        self.crop.water()

    def __init__(self, size, crop):
        self.size = size
        self.crop = crop()

class Combine():
    def harvest(self, field):
        quantity = field.crop.harvest() * field.size
        return quantity
```